# Return two different objects from a single method in Java

Tags: java

Hi I am  trying to return two array, 1 as string and another as float; 
return both 
i searched on net it was confusing, i am new to oops

```
public String[][]  loadcost(String[][] arr2, int tcount) {

        int f1 = 1;
        int f2 = 0;
        int[] costarr = null ;


        while (f2 < tcount){

            arr2[f1][f2] = cost.nextLine();
            costarr[f2] = Integer.parseInt (arr2[f1][f2]);
            f2 = f2 + 1;                            
        }

        Arrays.sort(costarr);
        return arr2 , costarr ;
```

my original request is to sort an 2-d array, it dint work with the code what i got on net

BBB 444
 DDD 098
 FF  19.01

would like to sort using the second column

Comment: you can only return one value from a method

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a object containing two arrays of whatever type you want and then return that from this method as methods can only return one object.

```
class MyObjectName {
  String[] stringArray;
  Float[] floatArray;
}

public MyObjectName loadcost(String[][] arr2, int tcount) {
   .....
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use a wrapper class to wrap the two arrays, and return that:

```
public class Wrapper {
    public final String[] strings;
    public final float[] floats;

    public Wrapper(String[] strings, float[] floats) {
        this.strings = strings;
        this.floats = floats;
    }

}
```

Your method would then have a return type of `Wrapper` and would return a `new Wrapper(arr2, costarr)`:

```
public Wrapper  loadcost(String[][] arr2, int tcount) {

        int f1 = 1;
        int f2 = 0;
        float[] costarr = null ;


        while (f2 < tcount){

            arr2[f1][f2] = cost.nextLine();
            costarr[f2] = Float.parseFloat (arr2[f1][f2]);
            f2 = f2 + 1;                            
        }

        Arrays.sort(costarr);
        return new Wrapper(arr2, costarr)
}
```

(By the way, I made `costarr` of type `float[]` rather than `int[]`.)

You could then access the wrapped arrays with:

```
wrapper.floats //float array
wrapper.strings //String array
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java you cannot return two values (this is not python :P). However you can create an object with only the purpose of keep your values together. This tecnique is called encapsulation.

For more info, check the follow link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public class myarrayl {

        String [][] arr;
        int [] costarr;

    }

        public myarrayl loadcost(String[][] arr2, int tcount) {

            int f1 = 1;
            int f2 = 0;
            int[] costarr = null ;
            myarrayl content = null;    

            while (f2 < tcount){

                arr2[f1][f2] = cost.nextLine();
                costarr[f2] = Integer.parseInt (arr2[f1][f2]);
                f2 = f2 + 1;

            }

            Arrays.sort(costarr);
            content.arr = arr2;
                    content.costarr = costarr;
            return content;

    }
```

to access

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow are better when they include some discussion/explanation along with example code.